# Joining two tables using Hibernate to get result in JSON

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

Hi i am newbie to hibernate. I have two entities/tables and i need to combine them to get the both tables as a single JSON response.i.e when i make a call to tenant table along with the tenant details the tenant related binary data also has to be retrieved. Here is my table details

```
Table tenant;

 id(primary key),
 binary_id(foreign key)(primary key in binary table),
 name

Table binary;

 id(primary key),
 tenant_id(foreign key)(primary key in tenant table),
 fileLocation,
 description
```

Each tenant will have multiple records in binary table. i.e each tenant will have multiple binary_id's which have entry in binary table .

My SQL is something like

```
  SELECT tenant.name,binary.description,binary.fileLocation FROM Tenant tenant,Binary binary WHERE tenant.binary_id=binary.id
```

I am not sure how to do it in hibernate.

Can some one please help me how i can get tenant and tenant related binary table data in response as a JOSN.

my tenantMapper class:

```
    /**
 * Mapping from 'TenantEntity' to 'Tenant'
 * @param tenantEntity
 */
public Tenant mapTenantEntityToTenant(TenantEntity tenantEntity) {
    if(tenantEntity == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //--- Generic mapping 
    Tenant tenant = map(tenantEntity, Tenant.class);

    //--- Link mapping ( link to SwaBinary )
    if(tenantEntity.getBinary() != null) {
        tenant.setBinaryId(tenantEntity.getBinary().getId());
    }
    return tenant;
}


/**
 * Mapping from 'Tenant' to 'TenantEntity'
 * @param tenant
 * @param tenantEntity
 */
public void mapTenantToTenantEntity(Tenant tenant, TenantEntity tenantEntity) {
    if(tenant == null) {
        return;
    }

    //--- Generic mapping 
    map(tenant, tenantEntity);

    //--- Link mapping ( link : tenant )
    if( hasLinkToBinary(tenant) ) {
        BinaryEntity Binary1 = new BinaryEntity();
        Binary1.setId( tenant.getBinaryId() );
        tenantEntity.setBinary( Binary1 );
    } else {
        tenantEntity.setBinary( null );
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You may want to have a look at OneToMany relations in Hibernate to get Java Objects out of your database model

Comment: @Nitek    i wrote like this  but it is getting tenant table alone                                                    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tenant", targetEntity=BinaryEntity.class)
                                                                                                       private List<BinaryEntity> listOfBinary;

Comment: Can you please provide more of your code? (at least your mapped classes and the code generating your JSON)

Comment: @Nitek i edited my post. Added mapper class for tenant